# Excel VBA Datasheet Query Excel 2013

Tags: c#, excel, vba

In my c# application I create an excel workbook with multiple sheets

1 sheet has a column of different links
the end sheet is a bunch of data that has the autofilter applied.

I also put in a skeleton Worksheet_followhyperlink method into sheet 1 that just msgboxes letting me know I got the macro inserted correctly.

The Idea that I want to do is to be able to click a link on sheet 1, using its name  (Target.Name) to filter/query the data on sheet 2, and be able to output the data onto a blank sheet 3.

I also for convenience in hoping it helped, inserted a Defined Name for the range of the data in Sheet 2.

My question is, where do I go from here.  All the searches I have done have not given me many clues, and I admit my google-fu is not the best.

Thanks in advance for any help or links one can give.  Code is always helpful if you have any.

Thanks

-Z